# Using fast api and mongo in backend; getting "value_error.missing" for get request

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoose, fastapi

I have defined my get route as mentioned below here

```
app = FastAPI()
@app.get('/audioFileType')
async def read_audioFileType(audioFileType: AudioFileType):
    audioList = []
    if hasattr(audioFileType, 'song') :
        for audiofile in db.audioList.find():
            audioList.append(Song(**audiofile))
        return { 'audioFileType': audioList }
```

I am using Mongo in backend.
My model structure is as below.

```
class Song(BaseModel):
    id: PyObjectId = Field(alias='_id')
    name: str
    duration: int
    uploaded_time: datetime

class Podcast(BaseModel):
    id: PyObjectId = Field(alias='_id')
    name: str
    duration: int
    uploaded_time: datetime
    host: str
    participants: str

class AudioBook(BaseModel):
    id: PyObjectId = Field(alias='_id')
    title: str
    author: str
    narrator: str
    duration: int
    uploaded_time: datetime

class Config:
    arbitrary_types_allowed = True
    json_encoders = {
        ObjectId: str
    }

class AudioFileType(BaseModel):
    song: List[Song]
    podcast: List[Podcast]
    audioBook: List[AudioBook]

class audioFileMetadata(BaseModel):
    id: PyObjectId = Field(alias='_id')
    metadata = str
```

I am getting the error which is as below:

```
"type": "value_error.missing"
```

Can anyone put his/her valuable thoughts on that?

Comment: How are you using the API?

Comment: here is the complete app.py https://pastebin.com/CLjVF7FY

Comment: And the models https://pastebin.com/u6w3q7JH

Answer (score 0):

Log and examine the content of db.audioList.find().
Some required field is missing.
Than than you may make this missing field optional like this:

```
from typing import Optional


class Song(BaseModel):
    id: PyObjectId = Field(alias='_id')
    name: str
    duration: Optional[int] = None
    uploaded_time: datetime
```